# The roadmap to an Android development expert

Tags: android

I just started to learn Android development.

My previous experience is majorly .NET framework in C#. I have some experience with Linux and basically no idea about Java.

So, which is the good way to be an Android development expert? Books? Study roadmap? Anything would be appreciated. I am all ears to your advises.

Thanks.

(Apologies if this is not the right place to post such a question.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first thing you must do is learn Java.  [Head First Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009208) would be a nice introduction.  Android applications commonly use complex Java concepts, such as inner classes, anonymous classes, generics, etc. You should become a Java expert before becoming an Android expert.  It will make your life alot easier.

After this I would recommend learning Android by reading an intro book such as [Beginning Android 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430226293).

After this -- or as a supplement to the book -- go check out the [android developer's guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html), where you will get tons of great tips and sample code. Make sure you understand all of this sample code.

Somewhere along the way, you should check out [this wonderful tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/10/android-full-application-tutorial.html) on creating a "real-life" application.  It goes step-by-step and helped me alot.

Comment: If not an expert, at least proficient

Answer (score 4):

If you have worked with C# then it should be no problem simply "jumping in"... it's basically the same language, you just have to learn the libraries like anybody else. Just remember to compare strings with .equals() instead of == :) Microsoft did a might fine job evolving (*cough* copying *cough*) the Java language so you should feel right at home :)

Seriously, you don't need to bother much with learning Java per-se, just get Eclipse, [install the SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and start [read the developper's guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html). AFAIK there aren't any good Android books out there, but there are a lot of interesting videos [here](http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html). The videos should be your best source of information really...

Comment: Not learning the idiosyncrasies of Java first will result in alot of headaches down the road.  You will be able to follow along tutorials, but when you are creating original apps, you will have a lot of trouble.  You will never be an Android expert without first being a Java expert.

Comment: Have you ever write a Java and .NET code? Don't you see i.e objectivity differences between those languages?

Comment: There are differences of course, but nothing that important. I have written some Windows forms code (although I have about 5 times more experience with JAVA) and to be honest they are quite the same to me. Sure, C# has delegates (use interfaces with one/two methods instead), properties (use getters and setters instead) and structs (just use beans)... Sure there are caveats such as the string comparisons and the passing of structs as parameters but you can addapt very quickly...

Answer (score 4):

I learned Java and Android at the same time (had **no** previous experience with Java). I can't really say that my first apps were particularly good but, as with anything else, you get better with time and experience. Now I'm working a full time job developing Android apps (after a few open-source projects) :)

I guess it depends on how you prefer to learn. I started by jumping right in and doing [some tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial) and some small apps for myself, so that's all I can recommend (I have not read any Android books). If you want something to read, [the developer's guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) will keep you entertained for at least a few hours.

Comment: You learned them on your own and now you are a software engineer on facebook? Teach me master

Answer (score 0):

For Java I would recommend Thinking in Java, for Android you can find sth interesting (for beginners) here http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial . Personally I tried to read some books about android but they are not particulary interesting (Pro Android 2).

Answer (score 0):

If u want to make a career in Android, first learn basics in JAVA.
Read *JAVA The Complete Reference* book to improve your understanding.
Then start learning Android. Using Google search will provide you a lot of video tutorials to learn android.

check out [Google I/O developer conference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_I/O) and also this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7SxNNC429U)